# Number of built-in functions in V14

Tags: version-14, wolframlanguagesymbol

From my point of view, there is a discrepancy regarding the number of built-in functions (= Symbols) in Mathematica, version 14. According to SW's Release Announcement blog post, there should be approx. 6600 functions ([The Story Continues: Announcing Version 14 of Wolfram Language and Mathematica](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2024/01/the-story-continues-announcing-version-14-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/)).

With a `WolframLanguageSymbol` call, I only get a little more than 6300 symbols.

```
EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "EntityCount"]
```

yields

```
6318
```

... and the difference to V13.3 is

```
EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "VersionIntroduced" -> 14]["EntityCount"]

54
```

Any comments?

Comment: There are some things in `Names["*"]` that are missing from the entity list, for example deprecated functions like `URLFetch` and `ToDate` that have been replaced with new functions, functions like `Into` which have no documentation, and many other things like options, box forms, formal symbols etc. In that blog post, they must be counting some of these extra things.

Comment: May be the 6600 includes also experimental ones. For example on V 14, I get `Length[Names["System`*"]]` gives `7538` while in V 13.3.1 this gives `7478` but this includes everything in System context. Including experimental and everything else (not only built-in functions). To get list of new symbols/functions in V 14, the command is `EntityList[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol","VersionIntroduced"->14]]`   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkpQz.png)

Comment: I could never figure out how to use Entity stuff to only list **built-in** function. I.e. not including Symbols also, such as `K` and `C` and so on.  Which are all in system context.

Comment: The differences can be observed with: ```SymmetricDifference[EntityValue[EntityList["WolframLanguageSymbol"], "Name"], Names["System`*"]]```

Comment: @Nasser: Very odd, but for Length[Names["System*"]] I get 49 in both my installs of V 14.

Comment: @Moo, Nasser's comment got misformated – you have to use a backtick before an asterisk: ```Names["System`*"]```

Comment: Thanks @Domen - that did the trick! It shows 7544 instead of 7538, but maybe that is due to some system related stuff with the OS and like, I suppose.